# Trying to compile mongoose into a C++ raspberry pi project

Tags: c++, linux, webserver, raspberry-pi, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to write a C++ program to collect data from my Pi B+ and send it to a webpage via mongoose webserver. I'm having trouble compiling the code, I get the following errors:

```
mongoose.c: In function ‘void mg_send_data(mg_connection*, const void*, int)’:
mongoose.c:1562:54: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
mongoose.c:717:13: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void write_chunk(connection*, const char*, int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

In my main C++ file I have:

```
extern "C" {
        #include <time.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include "mongoose.h"
        #include <math.h> 
}

int main()
{
   ...code...
}
```

and I compile with

```
g++ application.cpp mongoose.c -o application -Wall -pthread -ldl -lm
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm not actually making any mongoose calls, just trying to compile it into the executable. I don't want to edit the mongoose source code, perhaps that's the only way to do it?

Comment: `mongoose.c` should be compiled with a C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.c` should be compiled with a C compiler, as C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `[const] void *` to `[const] any_other_type *`. In C this is allowed.

Comment: Mongoose is now both ISO C++ 98 and ISO C 90 compliant. You're correct about conversion rule. Also, mongoose can be compiled by either C++ and C compilers, since it does explicit type conversions where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

An up-to-date release of mongoose can be compiled with g++.

I just compiled with g++ your sample with release [tags/5.5](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/releases/tag/5.5)